# print text with stored user inputs, wihout ([''], ', ')

Tags: python

Python 2.7
I am asking the user information and then store it like this:
user_Name = []

I print out questions that looks like this:
Q_2 = user_Name, ", How old are you ?"

the output of print Q_2 is:
(['abobex'], ', How old are you ?')

All the inputs the user input is stored and i can print out all of them, but it prints out ([''], ', ?') instead of just: abobex, How old are you ?

I have tested changed alot within the print and some solutions did not print out everything correct.
I bet it is a easy problem, im new to python.
a sample of the code:

```
user_Name = []
Q_2 = user_Name, ", How old are you ?"
print Q_2
input = raw_input()
user_Age.append(input)
user_Age = input
```

is there something i can tell raw_input() to do or the print statement ?

Comment: Really unclear from what you have posted. Your code sample will not even work. `user_name = raw_input('What is your name?')` then `user_age = raw_input('%s, how old are you?' % user_name)` is probably pretty close to what you want.

Comment: Why do you define `user_Name` to be a `list`?

Comment: Try : user_Name = ""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's displaying the username with brackets because `user_Name` is an array containing a string. The parentheses are there because `Q_2` is being assigned a tuple value - to correctly concatenate strings, use the plus sign, not a comma.

If you want to get the actual username to print in the string, and assign a string instead of a tuple to Q_2, you'd simply have:

`Q_2 = user_Name[0] + ", how old are you?"`.

However, there are a few unnecessary things in your code. For one, you can pass the question string to raw_input like: `input = raw_input(Q_2)`

In fact, your code as posted could be condensed to this:

`user_Age.append(raw_input(user_Name[0] + ", how old are you?"))`

It's also not clear why you're appending `input` to user_Age, which I assume is a list, but then replacing that list with `input` - you're essentially throwing away your list.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the comma, `user_Name, ", How old are you ?"` forms a tuple and the `print` statement prints it as such. This is different from `print user_Name, ", How old are you ?"`.

Try a simple string concatenation (make `user_Name` a string):

```
Q_2 = user_Name + ", How old are you ?"
```

Comment: Their `user_Name` is a `list`.  This will give a `TypeError`.

Comment: @SethMMorton That's why *"make `user_Name` a string"*.

Comment: Sorry about that.  You are correct.